# Generating 5 state's weather hyperlink and a summary from RSS feeds using a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, rss

My goal here is to choose   a   state   from    a   drop    down    list.   Upon    choosing    a   state,  my  web page    should  display the title   and summary 
for each    warning for the selected    state.  The title   should  be  hyperlinked to  the URL that    can be  found   in  the link    element of  the item. Each individual warning should contain a hyperlink and a summary. I am currently unsure how to display this data with the code I currently have. I am using cases as of now, I think this is the best way to do this process.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="stateDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="stateDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>Select a State</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Alabama</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Indiana</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>California</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Illinois</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Minnesota</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList><br /><hr /><br />
</div>

<div style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Arial">

//This is the area for output, not really sure what would be the best to use to display the data.

</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CS.

```
namespace WebForm1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void stateDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String headlineTopic = stateDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList items = document.GetElementsByTagName("item");

        switch (headlineTopic)
        {
            case "Alabama":
                document.Load("http://www.weather.gov/alerts/al.atom");
                foreach (XmlNode n in items)
                {
                    Response.Write("<p><a href='" + n["link"].InnerText + "'>" + n["title"].InnerText + n["Summary"].InnerText + "</a></p>");
                }
                break;

            case "Indiana":
                document.Load("http://www.weather.gov/alerts/in.atom");
                foreach (XmlNode n in items)
                {
                    Response.Write("<p><a href='" + n["link"].InnerText + "'>" + n["title"].InnerText + n["Summary"].InnerText + "</a></p>");
                }
                break;

            case "California":
                document.Load("http://www.weather.gov/alerts/ca.atom");
                foreach (XmlNode n in items)
                {
                    Response.Write("<p><a href='" + n["link"].InnerText + "'>" + n["title"].InnerText + n["Summary"].InnerText + "</a></p>");
                }
                break;

            case "Illinois":
                document.Load("http://www.weather.gov/alerts/il.atom");
                foreach (XmlNode n in items)
                {
                    Response.Write("<p><a href='" + n["link"].InnerText + "'>" + n["title"].InnerText + n["Summary"].InnerText + "</a></p>");
                }
                break;

            case "Minnesota":
                document.Load("http://www.weather.gov/alerts/mn.atom");
                foreach (XmlNode n in items)
                {
                    Response.Write("<p><a href='" + n["link"].InnerText + "'>" + n["title"].InnerText + n["Summary"].InnerText + "</a></p>");
                }
                break;
    }
  }   
 }
}
```